# Validate out of process COM Server client is trusted

Tags: c#, c++, security, com

I have an out of process COM Server that exposes a method I do not want called by code I do not trust.

Basically what I'm trying to do is prevent a clever customer calling these methods that I need access too. I respect that a different solution all together should be considered. But for reasons I rather not get into I don't really have that option.  I can go with a less than robust solution, but would prefer to get as robust as possible.

I have the ability to change both the client and the server code. The server is written in C++ and the client is written in C#.

What's the best way to secure these calls?

I figured that such a problem would not be uncommon for interprocess communications or remote procedure calls. So I'm hoping there is an acceptable industry best practice, or maybe even a straight forward COM solution. In the absence of such, I'm leaning towards grabbing underlining data from the arguments and using pieces of that data as a string to encrypt using a key from another piece of the data and pass that to the server to be validated.

Comment: Define "trust". What does it mean for you to "trust" a piece of code? What is your threat model - exactly what kind of attacks are you trying to protect against?

Comment: original post edited.

Comment: Well, if it's security by obscurity you be wanting, then, for example, have the client pass a string that, if you only consider every 5th character, reads "The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain"; all the other characters are randomly generated by the client (to obscure the pattern), and ignored by the server. How long this scheme will stand depends on how "clever" your customers are. There's no 100% effective way to protect a program from a determined attacker that physically controls the hardware said program runs on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That approach sounds trivially susceptible to replay.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: That approach is trivially susceptible, period. That seems what the OP wants. However, if you insist; have the client add time of day to the string, have the server verify that the time is, say, within one minute of now (works as long both parties are on the same machine, working off the same clock). Or, at the expense of more complexity, have a challenge/response protocol; the client first calls another method that returns a random nonce, then calls the real method passing back that nonce, XORed with some shared key. All this is just putting lipstick on a pig, of course.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I prefer to have a robust solution if possible and ideally what might be considered a best practice if there is one. I have a similar idea that involves grabbing underlining data from the arguments and using pieces of that for data to encrypt using a key from another piece of the data.

Comment: .NET solves this problem by looking a the full public key stored in the strong-named key file of the caller. Can such a technique be used for COM calls? Is there a way to get process handle of the client, or even better, the module handle? I should add that my clients are C# and C++.

Comment: To my knowledge, .NET strong-name signing mechanism protects loading of assemblies, not remote cross-process calls. How would a process, whether written in C# or C++, determine which other process is calling it? Or that there isn't a system-wide hook installed by an attacker, making a call from inside the "right" process?

Comment: that's why I suggested module handle. One of my clients is in fact a DLL system-wide hook. Another is an office plugin ;)

Comment: Well, you could require the client to pass a file path of the DLL (or module handle - whatever is handy to point to the DLL), and verify the signature on that DLL. But that would only prove that a properly signed DLL exists on hard drive - not that the code making the call is actually part of that DLL. Or that the DLL is not patched in memory by the attacker, making calls on his behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's an out-of-box COM solution, or best practice I didn't find any. One common technique I found was to use a hash key. The client generates a key and passes it to the server. The server generates the same key and if it doesn't match the client's key, the call is rejected.

I based my hash key on some secret that is extracted from the underlying data that the API's are acting upon. Since my data is different with each use the key differs every time. Both sides have access to the underlying data before the call so they can generate the same key. I choose to base64 encode mine, only because I preferred passing a NULL-terminating character array instead of a byte array to the server.

```
LPCSTR      lpszSomeSecret  = "Some Secret To Be Hashed" ;
std::string strEncodedHash  ; // the resulting hash. 

HCRYPTPROV  hProv           = NULL ;
HCRYPTHASH  hHash           = NULL ;
DWORD       cbSomeSecret    = (DWORD)::strlen(lpszSomeSecret) ;
BYTE*       pbHash          = NULL ;
DWORD       cbHash          = 0 ;
DWORD       cbHashSize      = (DWORD)sizeof(cbHash) ;
LPSTR       pchEncodedHash  = NULL ;
int         cbEncodedHash   = 0 ;

HRESULT hResult = S_OK ;

if (!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) {
    hResult = ::AtlHresultFromLastError() ;
} else if (!::CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
    hResult = ::AtlHresultFromLastError() ;
} else if (!::CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)lpszSomeSecret, cbSomeSecret, 0)) {
    hResult = ::AtlHresultFromLastError() ;
} else if (!::CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHSIZE, (BYTE*)&cbHash, &cbHashSize, 0)) {
    hResult = ::AtlHresultFromLastError() ;
} else if ((pbHash = (BYTE*)::malloc(cbHash)) == NULL) {
    hResult = E_OUTOFMEMORY ;
} else if (!::CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, pbHash, &cbHash, 0)) {
    hResult = ::AtlHresultFromLastError() ;
} else if ((pchEncodedHash = (LPSTR)::malloc(
            (cbEncodedHash = ::Base64EncodeGetRequiredLength(cbHash, ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOPAD | ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOCRLF))
            )) == NULL) {
    hResult = E_OUTOFMEMORY ;
} else if (!::Base64Encode(pbHash, cbHash, pchEncodedHash, &cbEncodedHash, ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOPAD | ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOCRLF)) {
    hResult = E_FAIL ;
} else {
    strEncodedHash.assign(pchEncodedHash, cbEncodedHash) ;
}

if (pchEncodedHash) ::free(pchEncodedHash) ;
if (pbHash)         ::free(pbHash) ;
if (hProv)          ::CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0) ;
if (hHash)          ::CryptDestroyHash(hHash) ;
```